# How to play with friends that are using different online poker sites?

Tags: texas-hold-em, online

My friends are registered on many different online poker sites i.e. Paddy Power, Betfred, Skybet, William Hill.

I want to know how we can play against each other online on the same table but using different poker sites.

Answer (score 3):

if you plan on playing on these sites separately but on the same table, that is impossible because there is no way to connect to each other if you are on different sites. If you would like to play an online home-game type of game, I would suggest pokernow.club. It is super easy to invite your friends and all play together. You would have to take care of the finances yourselves though if you do not plan on using XLM which is supported by the site.